# Im trying to have a company send me ETH, but they saty they cannot "sync" with my Metamask wallet until it shows or has a transaction record. Correct

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, wallet-transfer

I have an incoming transfer that the sending person it saying that to sync with my Metamask wallet, the wallet has to show a transaction record.

Is this true and how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not, they can send you money with just your address.

Comment: Even if they are sending ETH?

Comment: Yes, even if theyre sending ETH

Answer (score 0):

i think its fruad
don't belive in that type of message

for transfer money to another address
only required is receiver public address

don't sync with your metamask wallet